# Chrome extension: Navigate to a url when user clicks on icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to exexute a javascript, that navigates the browser to some url, when user clicks on extension icon?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.update({
     url: "http://www.example.com/"
});
```

Comment: Posted 4 months after a much better answer, but still gets accepted and gets all the votes?!

Answer (score 10):

Use [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update)`({ url: "http://www.example.com/" })` in the `onClicked` listener of your browser action. When you omit the `tabId` argument, the update applies to the currently selected tab.

Despite being part of the `chrome.tabs` API, this does not require the `tabs` permission.

Answer (score 8):

You can also navigate active tab to required url ( without opening new tab )

```
chrome.tabs.query( { active: true, currentWindow: true }, function( tabs ) {
  chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: "http://stackoverflow.com//" } ); 
});
```